# Procedure in SQL Server with higer permission

Tags: sql-server, security

I need that user call procedure which will change context with exec as login. Problem, that if user don't have sysadmin server role it generates error

> Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal
>   "copy_user" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be
>   impersonated, or you do not have permission.

If I give user sysadmin server role everything works.

```
declare @ret int
exec @ret = testProc @id = 0
select @ret
```

and procedure is very simple

```
ALTER PROCEDURE testProc
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @c int

    exec as login = 'copy_user'
    select @c = COUNT(*) from Customers
    REVERT

    return @c;
END
GO
```

It should/will copy data to other database, so having user login with sysadmin isn't very Ok.

I also impersonate copy_user with:

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::copy_user TO copy_user WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO copy_user

GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::copy_user TO copy_user WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO copy_user
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE TO copy_user WITH GRANT OPTION

GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::cp TO copy_user
```

In general I need procedure that can insert data into other database (on same server), but not allow current user to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to achieve.

If you wish to have a database user that can only access data via stored procedures and not direct then all you need do is grant the relevant user execute permission on the stored procedure only. The user will be unable to access the database data directly.

Comment: User can access some data from tables or execute procedures, what I need is to allow switch execution context in some procedures to login that can access different database and write there some data. Problem that now context can be switched only for user who have sysadmin server role and I really don't want to do that for all users.

Comment: Why do you "need" to switch execution context? Does the Database User in question not exist in both databases? Have you enabled Cross Database Ownership Chaining?

Comment: I would like to have user only in one database and do not allow him to connect to second. Reason for that is that there's 2 companies who have some common data in one db that are use by both, and from one table data should go separate database for each company. So if I create user in all db to write data, he will be able to connect to other company database (and have possibility to change it) and I would like to avoid that.